# How can I achieve this effect using SVG and JS?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, svg

I've already built the animation part, used JS to control the  in SVG element.

Now what I want to achieve is something like this:

[image]

I tried to use paths.getBoundingClientRect() to get the distance between viewport's border to the path's highest position, so I can make the whole background change when the peak reaches a certain position. (if (rect.top <= 100) {...})

But I don't know how to control irregularly shaped areas' attributes.
Any possible solution?

Thank you very much.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Your question is pretty vague, you should read the "how do I ask" FAQ and revise your question to make it very specific and to show what you've already tried.  http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score -1, accepted):

i have used http://d3js.org for that sort of thing. it is very good. It provides a simple library to help you draw the graphs you want using svg. I think the particular part you are looking for is called library.
This is the API call.

- https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/SVG-Shapes#area

## Some links below to examples and code for using d3js

- http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3894205
- http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3883195
- http://mbostock.github.io/d3/talk/20111018/area-gradient.html
- http://bl.ocks.org/NPashaP/113f7fea0751fa1513e1
- http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/1667367